# Why isn't munin's apache_accesses report accesses?

Tags: munin

I have the ExtendedStatus enabled:

```
$ grep ExtendedStatus
/etc/apache2/mods-available/status.conf:ExtendedStatus On
```

But the "munin suggest" says it's still off:

```
root@SERVER:/etc/apache2# munin-node-configure --suggest|grep apache
apache_accesses            | yes  | no [ExtendedStatus option for apache mod_status is missing on port 11111]
apache_processes           | yes  | no                                     
apache_volume              | yes  | no [ExtendedStatus option for apache mod_status is missing on port 11111]
# The following plugins caused errors:
# apache_processes:
#   Junk printed to stderr
# ip_:
#   Nothing printed to stdout
...
```

Maybe the problem is that there is additional configuration if apache is listening on port 11111? I already restarted apache, munin. Using Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS with apache2 2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7.

UPDATE#1:

Apache is configured to listen on port 11111:

```
root@SERVER:~$ head -1 /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default 
<VirtualHost *:11111>
root@SERVER:~$
```

UPDATE#2:

The "/etc/munin/plugin-conf.d/munin-node" file has the:

```
[apache_*]
env.ssl yes
env.ports 11111
```

UPDATE#3:

If I use a:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://localhost:11111/server-status?auto -O -
```

On the server, then I get 401, since the users can only auth via LDAP.. maybe this is the problem.. how to allow the server-status on 127.0.0.1 before the LDAP auth?

UPDATE#4:

I tried to modify the "/etc/munin/plugins/apache_accesses" file..:

```
...
my $URL = exists $ENV{'url'} ? $ENV{'url'} : "https://usernamehere%40xx.foo.com:password@127.0.0.1:11111/server-status?auto";
#my $URL = exists $ENV{'url'} ? $ENV{'url'} : "http://127.0.0.1:%d/server-status?auto";
my @PORTS = exists $ENV{'ports'} ? split(' ', $ENV{'ports'}) : (11111);
...
```

and then..

```
root@SERVER:/etc/munin/plugins# ./apache_accesses autoconf
Possible unintended interpolation of @127 in string at ./apache_accesses line 90.
no (Port 11111: Can't connect to usernamehere                                   11111.foo.com:password.0.0.1:11111)
root@SERVER:/etc/munin/plugins#
```

The username contains a "@", but I escaped it to %40..:

```
usernamehere%40xx.foo.com
```

Comment: try:
netstat tnlp 
to check if 11111 is already in use.

Comment: Where is the output of the netstat?

Comment: It's used by apache already!

Comment: so probably your modules are not loaded properly take a look here:
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-configure-and-use-modules-in-the-apache-web-server